# Convert Query Parameters to Pretty URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have script file post.php which I'm using without `.php` extension using code below

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I want to use a pretty URL. For example, when I request the URL `/post/12` it should give me `$_GET` parameter `12` like I'm using with a query string: `post?id=12`.

Is it possible? Also, I don't want to direct all requests to `index.php`. Only requests that are made to `posts.php` script.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes.

Comment: This question contradicts itself. First you say you want to rewrite requests to `/post` to `/post.php`. Then you suddenly write that you want to rewrite those requests to `/index.php`. Now what?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle requests of the form `/post/12` with a separate rule, before your generic rewrite that appends the `.php` extension.

Try it like this:

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# Remove trailing slash if not a directory
# eg. "/post/" is redirected to "/post"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite "/post/<id>" to "/post.php?id=<id>"
RewriteRule ^(post)/(\d+)$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]

# Rewrite "/post" to "/post.php" (and other extensionless URLs)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Notes:

- MultiViews needs to be disabled for the second rule to work.
- Your initial rule that appends the `.php` extension was not quite correct. It could have resulted in a 500 error under certain conditions. However, the first *condition* was superfluous - there's no point checking that the request does not map to a file before checking that the request + `.php` *does* map to a file. These are mutually inclusive expressions.
- Without the first rule that removes the trailing slash (eg. `/post/` to `/post`) it raises the question of what to do with a request for `/post/` (without an *id*) - should this serve `/post.php` (the same as `/post`) or `/post.php?id=` (empty URl param)? Both of which are presumably the same thing anyway. However, these would both result in duplicate content (potentially), hence the need for a redirect.

Comment: That worked great. Just changed "\d+" to ".*" as id may not be integer.  Thanks a lot